# Change view by using computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have component of ViewControls, where have switchControls with which I can get the index of the clicked button. For example, i clicked first btn, and **snippetValue** will be 0, and so on.

```html
    <template>
    <SwitchControls v-model="snippetValue">
      <button>
        <i class="icon list" />
      </button>
      <button>
        <i class="icon grid" />
      </button>
    </SwitchControls>
    </template>
```

Question, how can i bind to a snippetValue (0 - 'list', 1 - 'grid') and emit params

```js
   emits: [ "update:modelValue" ],
    setup (props, { emit }) {
     const snippetValue = ref(0)

     const currentValue = computed({
       get: () => props.modelValue,
       set: (val: number) => {
         if (val === 0) {
           emit("update:modelValue", "list")
         }
         else {
           emit("update:modelValue", "grid")
         }
       },
     })
    },
```

parent.vue

```html
   <ViewControls v-model="snippetVariant"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the `v-model` directive from `SwitchControls` directly with computed property `currentValue`  :

```html
    <template>
    <SwitchControls v-model="currentValue">
      <button>
        <i class="icon list" />
      </button>
      <button>
        <i class="icon grid" />
      </button>
    </SwitchControls>
    </template>
```

```js
 emits: [ "update:modelValue" ],
    setup (props, { emit }) {
     const currentValue = computed({
       get: () => props.modelValue,
       set: (val: number) => {
           emit("update:modelValue", val === 0 ? "list" : "grid")
       },
     })
    },
```

Comment: It won't work, because snippetValue work, when i click first btn **snippetValue = 0**, when i click second btn **snippetValue = 1**

Comment: No need to use `snippetValue`

Comment: Oh, yes its works. But can it works if i need to use snippetValue in v-model?

Comment: Why do you need snippetValue?

Comment: Because the logic on the index is dependent in the component switchControls. There i add class, when index === currentIndex, so it works, when in v-model number

Comment: I need to compare if snippetValue = 0 emit list, snippetValue = 1 emit grid

Comment: I did that in computed setter